# Lync 2013: ConferenceFailureException "maxConferencesExceeded"

Tags: powershell, lync, lync-2013

After some googling I found that this reason if caused by too many scheduled conferences by my Application Endpoint. My only problem is, how do I delete/remove currently stored scheduled conferences for my application endpoint, when the only access I have to my server is through PowerShell??

EDIT:
Just found a command that actually could increase number of scheduled meetings per organizer (Set-CsUserServicesConfiguration -MaxScheduledMeetingsPerOrganizer 2000), but it didn't change the issue. I'm still receiving MaxConferencesExceeded error. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Get-CsUserServicesConfiguration to make sure the change has actually occurred, and/or setting it globally to make sure it has the correct context for your users.

I've also found with a large pool, it can take a while to kick in.

Have you tried republishing your Lync topology after making the change?  A bit dramatic, but can help with Lync gets itself into a knot with changes.

Comment: Will try that next time. Hopefully I can do it without republishing the Lync topology, which would be quiet an impact since my development environment is the same as local production.

Comment: FYI, Enable-CsTopology (as @Matthew Proctor stated), did make the changes to take action.